# Find minimum element in an array of unsorted integers faster than O (n)?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Is this possible to find the smallest element of an array of unsorted integers by faster than O (n) time complexity. 
Space complexity is not a concern.

Comment: The only way to search faster than `O(n)` would be to have a sorted array first.

Comment: @Cyber Some other constraints over the list might lead to a faster search than `O(n)`. Not only the "sorted" constraint.

Comment: @Jefffrey Yes (such as "the first element is the minimum", as in binary min-heaps), though that doesn't affect the answer here since there is no such constraint.

Comment: @delnan Never said it would. I was just stating that the statement Cyber made was... let's say "incomplete".

Comment: With Quantum Bogo Sort it is possible! http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?QuantumBogoSort

Comment: @ouah you beat me to it ;)

Comment: It could likely be done in O(log N) by using O(N) processors

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Given an arbitrary array of elements, you must look at each element *at least once* to definitively state that you have found the minimum element. This means that the necessary time complexity is `Ω(n)` [(see here for more information on Big Omega notation)](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/data-structures/big-o-versus-big-omega-notations/), meaning* that any algorithm that finds the minimum element will take at least `c * n` operations, where `c` is constant (in this case, `c >= 1`).

In other words, if an algorithm took less than `n` operations, then there must be at least one element in the array that the algorithm did not pass over. Since we have no information about this element (the array is arbitrary), we cannot say that this element is not smaller than the element the algorithm declared to be minimum. So the algorithm is incorrect.

<sub>* Note that this is not the formal meaning of Big-Omega notation, but it gets the point across. You can read about the formal definition [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Big-Omega).</sub>

Comment: I edited the answer. Please review it. Rollback if you find the edit inappropriate.

Comment: @Nawaz Wouldn't the answer make sense with or without the "not"? You can't know if the element is smaller than min, but you ALSO can't know if it's NOT smaller than min. You literally know nothing, as the next element could completely change the answer in either case.

Comment: @RickyMutschlechner That was my logic as well, but I think Nawaz's edit is more appropriate, as we're trying to find the minimum element, so by not being able to say that the element is not smaller, you can't claim that the algorithm is correct.

Comment: @Daniel ah, yes. Proof of correctness. Fair enough!